# 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid number value (infinite) in JSON write'

Tags: json, swift, firebase-realtime-database

What I want to do is: let user rate a store and then update the `storeRate` value in my Firebase.

[image]

After I clicked POST, I got the error:

> 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid number value (infinite) in JSON write'

```
//Initialize Variables
var storeRateIni = 0.0
var reviewCount = 0.0
var receivedId = 1             //receive storeId from parent View Controller

refStore = Database.database().reference().child("stores")
refUpdate = Database.database().reference().child("stores").child(String(receivedId))

refStore.observe(DataEventType.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    if snapshot.childrenCount > 0{
        for store in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]{
            let storeObject = store.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            let storeId = storeObject?["storeId"] as! Int
            if (storeId == self.receivedId) {
                //Get value store in Firebase
                let storeRate = storeObject?["storeRate"] as! Double
                let storeReviewCount = storeObject?["storeReviewsCount"] as! Double
                //Do the calculation
                let storeRateUpdate = (storeRate + self.userRate.rating) / storeReviewCount
                //Update to Firebase
                self.reviewCount = storeReviewCount + 1
                self.storeRateIni = storeRateUpdate
                self.refUpdate.updateChildValues(["storeRate": self.storeRateIni])                     
                self.refUpdate.updateChildValues(["storeReviewsCount": self.reviewCount])                         
}}}})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line,

```
let storeRateUpdate = (storeRate + self.userRate.rating) / storeReviewCount
```

generates `Double.inifinity` when `storeReviewCount == 0.0`, which is not representable in JSON.

You may need to handle the case `storeReviewCount == 0.0` separately from other cases.

For example:

```
let storeRateUpdate = storeReviewCount == 0.0
    ? 0.0
    : (storeRate + self.userRate.rating) / storeReviewCount
```

Comment: oh I figured out that I should update the reviewcount first, thx!